# Find Ellipse Size so that it Touches a Point

Tags: geometry

I have an ellipse with center point $O$, and angle $\theta$. What are the semi-axes $(a,b)$ for this ellipse so that it touches point $P$?

EDIT: I also have the $a/b$ ratio known.

EDIT:
With the help of the hint answer below, I solved this when the ellipse has $\theta=0$:

$\vec{d}=\vec{P}-\vec{O}$

$\theta_0=\arctan{\left(\left|\frac{d_y}{d_x}\right| \frac{a}{b}\right)}$

$(a,b)_{new}=\left(\frac{\left|d_x\right|}{\cos{\theta_0}},\frac{\left|d_y\right|}{\sin{\theta_0}}\right)$

Comment: Start with something simpler, like center at the origin and angle $0$. Then work your way from there.

Comment: That's the thing, I am not sure about the equations with the angle.

Comment: You don’t have enough information to determine a unique ellipse.

Comment: @amd If I have the $a/b$ ratio is that sufficient?

Comment: What do you **mean** by "angle $\theta$"?  The angle the major axis makes with the x-axis?

Comment: @user247327 yes!

Comment: You don’t need to know $\theta_0$ explicitly. You need its sine and cosine, which you can compute directly from the known tangent of the angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a solution for $\theta=0$, a straightforward way to proceed is to rotate $P$ about $O$ by $-\theta$, apply your solution, then rotate the resulting ellipse back.

Note that there’s no particular reason to compute the angle that you’re calling $\theta_0$ explicitly. (I’d use a different letter since it’s not really related to the axis angle.) In the equation of the ellipse, this angle only appears in the terms $\cos^2\theta_0$ and $\sin^2\theta_0$, which you can compute directly from the tangent of the angle via the identity $1+\tan^2\phi = \sec^2\phi$: if $m=\tan\phi$, then $\cos^2\phi = 1/(1+m^2)$ and $\sin^2\phi = m^2/(1+m^2)$.

On the other hand, you can compute the equation of the ellipse directly. A general equation of an ellipse with center at $O=(x_O,y_O)$ and major axis at an angle of $\theta$ from the $x$-axis is $$\frac1{a^2}\left((x-x_O)\cos\theta+(y-y_O)\sin\theta\right)^2+\frac1{b^2}\left((x-x_O)\sin\theta-(y-y_0)\cos\theta\right)^2 = 1.\tag{*}$$ This equation can be obtained from the standard equation by substituting equations of the minor and major axes for $x$ and $y$, respectively, or by performing the usual rotation and translation. You have a known point on the ellipse and also know that $a = kb$. Substitute these values into (*) and solve for $b$.

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is located at $(x_p,y_p)$, then you can say that the angle measured from the $x$-axis to $P$ is $\phi=\arctan\frac{y_p}{x_p}$. Then the ellipse can be parameterized by $x=a\cos\theta$ and $y=b\sin\theta$. What happens when $\phi=\theta$?